# How insert *char in vector <string> "[i]"? [C++]

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

sorry, for my bad english

i have `char *c` and I need insert in "i" position in a `vector <string>`

Can someone help?

Comment: The answer will vary greatly for whether the vector has more than, equal to or fewer than `i` elements before the insertion.  Which one is it?

Comment: Did you try looking at [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: @Curious equal to or fewer is the same case

Comment: @Slava one fewer and equal to is different from more than 2 fewer than (if you try and generalize)

Comment: @Curious I mean more than or equal is the same. Less than does not make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

`char *` can be (implicitly) converted to `std::string`, then insert it into proper position:

```
vec.insert( vec.begin() + i, std::string( c ) );
```

of course you need to be sure that `vec` size is bigger or equal than `i`. Details can be found in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

Answer (score 1):

To insert something in a vector you should use one of its methods `insert`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "Christian", "Assis" };
    const char *s = "Hello";
    size_t i = 0;

    v.insert( std::next( v.begin(), i ), s );

    for ( const auto &s : v ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello Christian Assis
```

You can add a check whether the value of the position `i` is less than or equal to the number of elements in the vector.

For example

```
v.insert( std::next( v.begin(), v.size() < i ? v.size() : i ), s );
```

Comment: Thanks Slava and Vlad!! :)

Sorry for the question, i just programming in C and I needed insert variables of C++.

I understood your expletives, they worked!